# Python InteractiveInterpreter - possible to interrupt running code?

Tags: python

If I have a `InteractiveInterpreter` object, which is running some code block via `runsource`, is there any method to interrupt this code at a later stage?

I've tried some approaches like another call to `runsource` with a

```
raise KeyboardInterrupt
```

call, but this doesn't affect the code running as a result of the earlier `runsource` call.

Comment: `runsource` is synchronous - it won't return until the code you've passed finishes running. What are you trying to interrupt?

Comment: Ah - i missed that the script was doing some other tricky things like replacing sys.stdout in order to redirect outputs (and trigger a Qt QCoreApplication.processEvents() call). This was mistakenly leading me to believe that the runsource call was returning control immediately. Anyway, I've been able to hack into the stdout replacement to fire KeyboardInterrupts there in certain circumstances, which allows the script to cancel.